# MS Access "This recordset is not updatable" in a SELECT query

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, subquery

I'm stumped regarding this message MS Access is giving me.

I am trying to run a SELECT query, with two sub-queries within it. All tables are local.

Could someone please explain to me why the following code is returning this error?

```
SELECT S.SKU, S.Date, S.[Order No], P.WSP, P.Average_Cost, S.[Item Status]
FROM [Item Detail Temp] AS S, [FD Worksheets Temp] AS P
WHERE [P].[SKU]=[S].[SKU] AND [P].[Date to use]=(SELECT MIN(P2.[Date to use])
                         FROM   [FD Worksheets Temp] P2
                         WHERE  P2.[SKU] = S.[SKU]
                         AND    P2.[Date to use] >= S.[Date]);
```

Giving it a google hasn't particularly helped. I have Macros enabled in security to make sure that wasnt it, and from what I can tell I dont have any sort of Grouping  in the code above that could cause the error?

Additionally, I believe the code does work just fine, but the whole time the loading bar is up that message is displayed in the bottom left corner of the screen. It also runs incredibly slow, and i'm sure i have run this query in the past without that message showing up, and also much quicker than it is currently.

Many thanks

EDIT: After looking a bit more, I have found a few possible reasons:

*"- It uses First(), Sum(), Max(), Count(), etc. in the SELECT clause. Queries that aggregate records are read-only.* - **There is a MIN() function, could that be causing it?**

*- It has a subquery in the SELECT clause. Uncheck the Show box under your subquery, or use a domain aggregation function instead."*

*- The fields in a JOIN are not indexed correctly: there is no primary key or unique index on the JOINed fields.* **There are no Unique Key fields, could that be the reason?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` your table sources and use the domain aggregate function, `DMin`, to make your query updateable.

```sql
FROM
    [Item Detail Temp] AS S
    INNER JOIN [FD Worksheets Temp] AS P
    ON [P].[SKU]=[S].[SKU]
WHERE
    [P].[Date to use]=
        DMin
            (
                "[Date to use]",
                "FD Worksheets Temp",
                "[SKU] = " & S.[SKU] & " AND [Date to use] >= " & Format(S.[Date], "\#yyyy-m-d\#")
            );
```

Comment: For some reason I am still getting a message saying "This recordset is not updatable.". What could be causing this?

Comment: Is either `Item Detail Temp` or `FD Worksheets Temp` a query instead of a table?

Comment: Could it be something to do with my Indexing? Would adding a primary key potentially solve this? Currently both tables have a non-unique index on the SKU and Date fields, but none have a unique one. I could make a unique index out of the 'FD Worksheets' table by combining the SKU and [Date to use], however doing the same would not work in the Item 'Detail table', as the same ID will be sold several times a day.

Comment: I was typing as you replied... No both are local tables. They are tables linked to a split database on the local network

Comment: If `SKU` is unique in one table but not the other (ie a one-to-many relationship), Access should allow you to edit values of fields from the table on the "many" side.  But if `SKU` is not unique in either table, I think that's why Access treats your query result as not updateable.

Answer (score 1):

Hans, I noticed you deleted you comment. I got it just in time, and it works perfectly. The query now runs in less than a second, compared to the 5-10 mins it was before.

I managed using the following:

```
SELECT S.SKU, S.Date, S.[Order No], P.WSP, P.Average_Cost, S.[Item Status]
FROM [Item Detail Temp] AS S, [FD Worksheets Temp] AS P
WHERE
        [P].[SKU]=[S].[SKU] 
    AND [P].[Date to use]=
            DMin
                (
                    "[Date to use]",
                    "FD Worksheets Temp",
                    "[SKU] = " & S.[SKU] & " AND [Date to use] >= " & Format(S.[Date], "\#yyyy-m-d\#")
            );
```

Comment: Ok, my fault for being too eager. I will use the corrected one. Thank you again Hans!

Answer (score 0):

Your query contains aggregate function `MIN`, tables should be joined using `JOIN` clause, also join columns should be indexed, details table should be joined using column with unique index, normally it's primary key.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I dont think it's possible to create a Unique index on these data sets. One table consists of sales which will of course have duplicated IDs, and the other table are the Product Prices.  The product prices table is one that adds about 50k records every day, essentially appending the whole product file with 'today's' price. This process should then match up all the prices to the sales by matching up the Product ID and Date. The files are only produced on weekdays however, which is where this code comes in, otherwise it would be a simple join.